# Azure Active Directory v2.0 Daemons and Server Side Apps Support

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Trying to get clarity as to if the current v2.0 endpoint supports the Daemons and server-side apps flow.

This article talks about the flows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-flows

It states:

> This article describes the types of apps that you can build by using Azure AD v2.0, regardless of your preferred language or platform. The information in this article is designed to help you understand high-level scenarios before you start working with the code.

Further it states:

> Currently, the types of apps in this section are not supported by the v2.0 endpoint, but they are on the roadmap for future development. For additional limitations and restrictions for the v2.0 endpoint

In the end I'm trying to build an app that connects to the Graph API that on a schedule connects to the API with "credentials" that allow it to access the API on behalf of a user that has allowed it to.

In my test harness I can get a token using:

```
var pca = new PublicClientApplication(connector.AzureClientId)
          {
             RedirectUri = redirectUrl
          };
var result = await pca.AcquireTokenAsync(new[] {"Directory.Read.All"},
                (Microsoft.Identity.Client.User) null, UiOptions.ForceLogin, string.Empty);
```

In the same harness I cannot get a token using:

```
var cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
                connector.AzureClientId,
                redirectUrl,
                new ClientCredential(connector.AzureClientSecretKey),
                null) {PlatformParameters = new PlatformParameters()};

var result = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { "Directory.Read.All" }, string.Empty);
```

This will result in:

> Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: AADSTS70011: The provided value for the input
> parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope Directory.Read.All is not
> valid.
> Trace ID: dcba6878-5908-44a0-95f3-c51b0b4f1a00
> Correlation ID: 1612e41a-a283-4557-b462-09653d7e4c21
> Timestamp: 2017-04-10 20:53:05Z

The MSAL package, Microsoft.Identity.Client (1.0.304142221-alpha), has not been updated since April 16, 2016. Is that even the package I should be using?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When using client credentials flow with Azure AD V2.0 , the value passed for the `scope` parameter in this request should be the resource identifier (Application ID URI) of the resource you want, affixed with the `.default` suffix. For the Microsoft Graph example, the value is https://graph.microsoft.com/.default.

Please click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds) for more details . And [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) is a tutorial for using  client credentials flow with Azure AD V2.0 endpoint.

Comment: That was what I needed! Got it working. Want to further test some scenarios. How can we revoke the admin consent?

Comment: I found the applications listed in the Azure Portal under Enterprise Applications for the appropriate AzureAD tenant.

Comment: Last link is dead.